# Alight two buttons in the same Horizontal Line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am trying to make the "Save" and "Attach Pic" buttons align at the top of my xml page but I can't quite get it to work. I got it to the point where the buttons would align just not in the same horizontal line. Oh, and is there any way that I can make both buttons align in the top left and top right corners? 
Here is the xml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="#ffffff" >

  <!-- Footer Start -->

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/footer"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="90dip"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:background="@layout/footer_repeat"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >
  </LinearLayout>
  <!-- Footer Ends -->


  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:padding="10dip" >

      <!-- Save button -->

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/btnSavePic"
          style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
          android:text="@string/savePic"
          android:layout_gravity="top|left"/>

       <Button
          android:id="@+id/btnAttachPic"
          style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
          android:text="@string/attachPic"
          android:layout_gravity="top|right"/>
  </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Added picture:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=4ihut4&s=5#.Uj9eHBbnZAh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using an eclosing LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  >


  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnSavePic"      
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
      android:text="@string/savePic"
      />

   <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnAttachPic"
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
      android:text="@string/attachPic"
      />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Hope it will work. 
Change your orientation to horizontal in 
So that you can get the buttons in horizontal alignment.

Pls vote if it get works.